# Retrieve single JSON element in an JSON object in angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I have a JSON  as

```
   labelnames={
    "one": "",
    "two": "",
    "three": "",
    "four": ""
};
```

Now i have separate condition for each `labelname`. So, if i wish to display `labelname[0]` i.e., "one" and use it, then what is the way i should follow?

I tried using pipes and ngfor loop, but i am getting all values in labelnames

```
 <li *ngFor="let doc of labelnames | keys">
 {‌{doc.key}}
</li>
```

I just need single element depending on index.

Help me in solving this.

Comment: First of all format your code properly, secondly do you really want to use that `keys` pipe?

Comment: Second of all learn what the term "JSON" means. What you have is not JSON--it's a JavaScript object. Learn how to refer to a property of a JavaScript object so people know what you mean--they are not called "elements". Learn the difference between "objects" and "arrays"--`labelname[0]` would be the first element in an **array** called `labelname`, not the first property in an object. We don't know what you mean by "separate condition for each `labelname`. Condition to do what?

Comment: @torazaburo from what I understand, he/she wants to iterate the keys of the object, he has been (trying) to do it manually by listing all keys and/or values, but wants to iterate with `*ngFor` instead. At least that is what I understood and based my answer on. I might be totally wrong though :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

Your Object:

```
obj= { "one": "", "two": "", "three": "", "four": "" };
```

Method in Component:

```
keys() {
    return Object.keys(this.obj);
}
```

Your html:

```
<p *ngFor="let key of keys()">{{key}}</p>
```

That will output:

```
one
two
three
four
```

EDIT, and some sugar on the top... if you need to display all keys and the value of the keys, this would be the way to go:

```
obj2 = { "one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3", "four": "4" };
```

And in the view:

```
<p *ngFor="let key of keys()">{{key}}: {{obj2[key]}}</p>
```

That would display:

```
one: 1
two: 2
three: 3
four: 4
```

EDIT2: Rereading your question, got me thinking again, maybe I misunderstood, is this what you needed:

```
objValue = Object.keys(obj)[0] // put which index you want
```

which will output

```
one
```

Well, now I think I have all bases covered in this answer! :D
More about `Object.keys` here: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Great!, glad to help! Since it solved your question, please consider accepting the answer! More info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 thanks!:)